# Adding column that has several states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-migrations

How to add a column through rails migration that has several states? I know that boolean can have two states. But what if I want more than 2 states?

What should I include in the command below if I want column to have 4 states? Those 4 states would be called "large", "medium", "small", "extra_small"...

```
rails generate migration add_column_to_users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store a specific set of values, you might be interested by enumerators.

**Enumerators in Rails**

The first solution is with `ActiveRecord::Enum` (see [doc](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html))

Example :

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end
```

The drawback of this solution is that you actually store an `int` or `string` type in the database, so the constraint is not really enforced.

**Database enumerator**

The second possibility is to use a native Enum type, should your RDBMS supports it.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
  name VARCHAR(40),
  size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);
```

With this solution though, the constraint is enforced, but if you need a new value in your set, you need a database migration.

Documentations:

- [MySQL Enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html)
- [PostgreSQL Enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have compelling performance concerns using a simple `VARCHAR` (`:string` type) column is usually fine.

Store your valid states in an array and you can set up validations on your model to ensure that the supplied state is correct.